# How handle errors with JS fetch again Laravel Api

Tags: javascript, laravel, xmlhttprequest, fetch

#### My Goal

I would like to display the error messages in the Form. But for this I would need to have access to the JSON?

#### Code

**HTML blade**

```html
<form>
    <input name="name">
    <p class="text-red-500 text-xs italic">Please fill out this field.</p> {{-- $message  --}}
    <button id="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

**javascript**

```js
<script>
        const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const fel = document.getElementById('commentForm');            
            const formData = new FormData(fel);
            const url = '/api/comments';
            let fetchData = {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
                headers: new Headers()
            }

            fetch(url, fetchData)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject(response);
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Success");
                console.log(data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (typeof error.json === "function") {
                    error.json().then(jsonError => {
                        console.log("Json error from API");
                        console.log(jsonError);
                    }).catch(genericError => {
                        console.log("Generic error from API");
                        console.log(error.statusText);
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log("Fetch error");
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
</script>
```

#### Response after a faulty request

`HttpStatus: 400`

```
// console.log(res) output
Response { type: "basic", url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: "Bad Request", headers: Headers, body: ReadableStream, bodyUsed: false }
​
body: ReadableStream { locked: false }​
bodyUsed: false​
headers: Headers {  }​
ok: false​
redirected: false​
status: 400​
statusText: "Bad Request"​
type: "basic"​
url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments"
​
<prototype>: ResponsePrototype { clone: clone(), arrayBuffer: arrayBuffer(), blob: blob(), … }
repellendus-dolor-quibusdam-sint-qui-news:147:29
```

#### Problem

In the Devtool Network tab, when I go to response of the request, I get a JSON

`JSON: {"comment_content":["The comment content field is required."],"comment_name":["The comment name field is required."]}`

When I output `res.json()` via the console within my fetch method, I get a Promise:

```
XHRPOSThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments
[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 100ms]
Promise { <state>: "pending" }​
<state>: "fulfilled"​
<value>: Object { comment_content: (1) […], comment_name: (1) […] }​​
comment_content: Array [ "The comment content field is required." ]​​
comment_name: Array [ "The comment name field is required." ]​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

**Additional question:**
Is there a better way to display the errors from the response in the form? Maybe with the help of the form data object?

Comment: You could iterate over the errors array, each key equals the name of one of your input fields. Afterwards you could append the paragraph by first searching for the name tag which is the key of the errors array. To get all the messages for a input field you will again have to iterate over all messages for one error.
Alternatively you could simply display all errors at the top, bottom or next to your form in a list. But this won't be that user friendly. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Considering you are making the request from JavaScript means you will also need to update the UI to reflect any error states. This includes targeting the right input elements based on the validation errors and appending them to the DOM. There may be libraries which can make this easier on the JS side but ultimately, you will need to write this logic.

As an aside, if you were using a traditional POST request, Laravel provides the [$errors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) variable and [@error](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#the-at-error-directive) blade directive. These help check for / display validation errors and are available in your application views. Since you are using blade, you may want to consider this.